Error when launching DLC 3.0.0rc4 environment Deeplabcut Windows 11
I am trying to create the deeplabcut environment on windows 11 on version 3.0.0rc4 on python 3.10.14, tensorflow = 2.10. I am using a local GPU. It will successfully create the environment, but it fails to launch.
Here is the code I used to install the environment (using the .yaml file from github (I added git to the dependencies)
conda env create -f DEEPLABCUT.yaml

conda activate deeplabcut

python -m deeplabcut 

The contents of the .yaml I used:
name: DEEPLABCUT
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - python=3.10
  - pip
  - ipython
  - jupyter
  - nb_conda
  - notebook<7.0.0
  - ffmpeg
  - pytables==3.8.0
  - git
  - pip:
    - "git+https://github.com/DeepLabCut/DeepLabCut.git@pytorch_dlc#egg=deeplabcut[gui,modelzoo,wandb]"

Error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\envs\deeplabcut\lib\runpy.py", line 187, in _run_module_as_main
    mod_name, mod_spec, code = _get_module_details(mod_name, _Error)
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\envs\deeplabcut\lib\runpy.py", line 146, in _get_module_details
    return _get_module_details(pkg_main_name, error)
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\envs\deeplabcut\lib\runpy.py", line 110, in _get_module_details
    __import__(pkg_name)
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\envs\deeplabcut\lib\site-packages\deeplabcut\__init__.py", line 76, in <module>
    from deeplabcut.pose_tracking_pytorch import transformer_reID
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\envs\deeplabcut\lib\site-packages\deeplabcut\pose_tracking_pytorch\__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from .train_dlctransreid import train_tracking_transformer
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\envs\deeplabcut\lib\site-packages\deeplabcut\pose_tracking_pytorch\train_dlctransreid.py", line 15, in <module>
    import torch
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\envs\deeplabcut\lib\site-packages\torch\__init__.py", line 148, in <module>
    raise err
OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found. Error loading "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\envs\deeplabcut\lib\site-packages\torch\lib\fbgemm.dll" or one of its dependencies.

How to resolve this?
I tried some suggestions following a few different posts:
https://forum.image.sc/t/compatibility-issues-while-installing-deeplabcut-with-gpu-in-windows-11/92235/5
and on
https://github.com/DeepLabCut/DeepLabCut/issues/2608
But I still have get errors
Now, after using darthbith's suggestion -
  Successfully uninstalled torch-2.4.0+cu118

(deeplabcut) C:\Users\hlyons\Desktop>python -m pip install torch==2.3.1
Collecting torch==2.3.1
  Using cached torch-2.3.1-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl.metadata (26 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: filelock in c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\deeplabcut\lib\site-packages (from torch==2.3.1) (3.15.4)
Requirement already satisfied: typing-extensions>=4.8.0 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\deeplabcut\lib\site-packages (from torch==2.3.1) (4.12.2)
Requirement already satisfied: sympy in c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\deeplabcut\lib\site-packages (from torch==2.3.1) (1.13.2)
Requirement already satisfied: networkx in c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\deeplabcut\lib\site-packages (from torch==2.3.1) (3.3)
Requirement already satisfied: jinja2 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\deeplabcut\lib\site-packages (from torch==2.3.1) (3.1.4)
Requirement already satisfied: fsspec in c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\deeplabcut\lib\site-packages (from torch==2.3.1) (2024.6.1)
Collecting mkl<=2021.4.0,>=2021.1.1 (from torch==2.3.1)
  Using cached mkl-2021.4.0-py2.py3-none-win_amd64.whl.metadata (1.4 kB)
Collecting intel-openmp==2021.* (from mkl<=2021.4.0,>=2021.1.1->torch==2.3.1)
  Using cached intel_openmp-2021.4.0-py2.py3-none-win_amd64.whl.metadata (1.2 kB)
Collecting tbb==2021.* (from mkl<=2021.4.0,>=2021.1.1->torch==2.3.1)
  Using cached tbb-2021.13.1-py3-none-win_amd64.whl.metadata (1.1 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: MarkupSafe>=2.0 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\deeplabcut\lib\site-packages (from jinja2->torch==2.3.1) (2.1.5)
Requirement already satisfied: mpmath<1.4,>=1.1.0 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\deeplabcut\lib\site-packages (from sympy->torch==2.3.1) (1.3.0)
Using cached torch-2.3.1-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl (159.8 MB)
Using cached mkl-2021.4.0-py2.py3-none-win_amd64.whl (228.5 MB)
Using cached intel_openmp-2021.4.0-py2.py3-none-win_amd64.whl (3.5 MB)
Using cached tbb-2021.13.1-py3-none-win_amd64.whl (286 kB)
Installing collected packages: tbb, intel-openmp, mkl, torch
ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
torchaudio 2.4.0+cu118 requires torch==2.4.0+cu118, but you have torch 2.3.1 which is incompatible.
torchvision 0.19.0 requires torch==2.4.0, but you have torch 2.3.1 which is incompatible.
Successfully installed intel-openmp-2021.4.0 mkl-2021.4.0 tbb-2021.13.1 torch-2.3.1

this is the error I am getting:
Loading DLC 3.0.0rc4...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\envs\deeplabcut\lib\runpy.py", line 187, in _run_module_as_main
    mod_name, mod_spec, code = _get_module_details(mod_name, _Error)
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\envs\deeplabcut\lib\runpy.py", line 146, in _get_module_details
    return _get_module_details(pkg_main_name, error)
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\envs\deeplabcut\lib\runpy.py", line 110, in _get_module_details
    __import__(pkg_name)
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\envs\deeplabcut\lib\site-packages\deeplabcut\__init__.py", line 61, in <module>
    from deeplabcut.modelzoo.video_inference import video_inference_superanimal
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\envs\deeplabcut\lib\site-packages\deeplabcut\modelzoo\video_inference.py", line 23, in <module>
    from deeplabcut.pose_estimation_pytorch.modelzoo.train_from_coco import adaptation_train
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\envs\deeplabcut\lib\site-packages\deeplabcut\pose_estimation_pytorch\__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from deeplabcut.pose_estimation_pytorch.apis import (
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\envs\deeplabcut\lib\site-packages\deeplabcut\pose_estimation_pytorch\apis\__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from deeplabcut.pose_estimation_pytorch.apis.analyze_images import (
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\envs\deeplabcut\lib\site-packages\deeplabcut\pose_estimation_pytorch\apis\analyze_images.py", line 27, in <module>
    from deeplabcut.pose_estimation_pytorch.apis.utils import (
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\envs\deeplabcut\lib\site-packages\deeplabcut\pose_estimation_pytorch\apis\utils.py", line 23, in <module>
    from deeplabcut.pose_estimation_pytorch.data.dataset import PoseDatasetParameters
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\envs\deeplabcut\lib\site-packages\deeplabcut\pose_estimation_pytorch\data\__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from deeplabcut.pose_estimation_pytorch.data.base import Loader
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\envs\deeplabcut\lib\site-packages\deeplabcut\pose_estimation_pytorch\data\base.py", line 20, in <module>
    from deeplabcut.pose_estimation_pytorch.data.dataset import (
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\envs\deeplabcut\lib\site-packages\deeplabcut\pose_estimation_pytorch\data\dataset.py", line 20, in <module>
    from deeplabcut.pose_estimation_pytorch.data.utils import (
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\envs\deeplabcut\lib\site-packages\deeplabcut\pose_estimation_pytorch\data\utils.py", line 21, in <module>
    from torchvision.ops import box_convert
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\envs\deeplabcut\lib\site-packages\torchvision\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from torchvision import _meta_registrations, datasets, io, models, ops, transforms, utils  # usort:skip
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\envs\deeplabcut\lib\site-packages\torchvision\_meta_registrations.py", line 163, in <module>
    @torch.library.register_fake("torchvision::nms")
AttributeError: module 'torch.library' has no attribute 'register_fake'


Can you add the commands you used to create the environment? Thank you!

I updated my original post, sorry about that!! @darthbith

Thank you! This seems to be an error with pytorch. I searched for the error message in the last line of the traceback: pytorch windows fbgemm.dll It seems like there is an error with version 2.4.0 of PyTorch on Windows 11 and it has been reported to GitHub: https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/131662 The fix seems to be python -m pip uninstall torch and then python -m pip install torch==2.3.1. But ideally this will be fixed by PyTorch itself, so eventually the answer will be to install pytorch 2.4.1 or later

@darthbith Hey! Thanks for that suggestion! When I ran that, an error occurred regarding dependency conflicts but still installs. Now, when I try to launch the environment a new error occurs involving torch.library. I have updated my question above to include this - if you have any insight :)!!

Great! Progress :-) It looks like you also need to install matching versions of at least torchvision plus any other pytorch-related packages.

@darthbith I may be misinterpreting the error- I not install the correct versions of torchvision and torchaudio because they are dependent on having torch 2.4 - thus 2.3.1 is incompatible?

Right, torchvision 2.4 requires torch 2.4. But if you install torchvision and torchaudio 2.3.1, then they will be compatible with torch 2.3.1
